# Rails ActiveRecord - Select user with most comments

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I wanted to select the User with the highest comments.

The comments are in a relation.

I can query them through:

```
User.first.comments
```

Now I wanted to select the User with the most comments.

I do not want to loop through the whole User-Table, because this is very time consuming.

Maybe something like this:

```
User.joins(:comments).find(:all, :order => "COUNT(comments) desc")
```

But this does not work.

If no solution is possible, I will cache them in an external table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a counter cache for that, here's an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then you must add a **comments_count** column to the **users** table and whenever a new comment is created with a user this field is incremented automatically. In the end, your query could be like this:

```
User.order( "comments_count desc" ).limit(10).all
```